# The encoded file is not permissioned error

Tags: php, html, xampp, ioncube

when I run the project then the following error displayed:

```
Fatal error: 
The encoded file C:\xampp\htdocs\anyfile.php is not permissioned for this server in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 2):

It simple means that **the script encoded by Ioncube Encoder cannot be used on your domain / ip / mac address**. Using encoded script may be limited to domain / ip / mac address and may even be limited in time. Different versions of encoder have different options to limit using script (you may look at [Ioncube versions comparison](http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php?page=pricing) to see what I'm talking about).

Comment: Can you tell me how to decoded this encoded source code by IonCube

Comment: The goal of encoding file is not to let anyone read file content. So there are no good methods to decode file to restore initial content

Comment: according to you there is no appropriate way

Comment: There isn't.  And even if there were. it would be violating rights owner of the script

Comment: I've tried at the moment on of online decrypters (where you have to pay) but you can decrypt one file as demo. File was very simple, only a few lines and everything I have "Decryption Impossible: Misc. Error". So even if it would work you cannot rely on it

Comment: thanxs @ Marcin Nabiałek