# Code downloaded from CPanel not workng

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have downloaded php code which has codeigniter framework. It is working fine in website but when I try to deploy it on localhost I am getting following exception

> Fatal error: 
>       The encoded file C:\xampp\htdocs\project3\application\libraries\layout.php is
>   not permissioned for this server in Unknown on line 0

Comment: did you try to make zip be fore downloading outside. ?

Comment: No i did not . we downloaded it through FTP

Comment: can you provide you `layout.php` in phpfiddle? if it contains iocubelib then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714673/the-encoded-file-is-not-permissioned-error hepls you

Comment: `application\libraries\layout.php` is not a standard CI file. Dont know why its there

Answer (score 1):

in the config/autoload.php  you should load layout library

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('layout');
```

if this doesn't help then the library is maybe encoded by [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/)  with `--allowed-server` option set to your domain name.

You may contact library developer and ask for files encoded with `--allowed-server` option set to any IP, or even better ask for open source code.

Comment: Yes it seems like they have encoded the layout.php with ioncube. What I have to do if i want to load it on localhost?

Comment: this article can give you an idea on how it works  http://bestioncubedecoder.blogspot.com.tr/

Comment: Instead of relying on decoders - which break all kinds of license agreements, and will most likely result in broken code - the best course of action is to contact the developer of the purchased script and ask for an appropriate license for local development.

Comment: yes I totally agree with @SebiH, besides using that kind of decoders does not guarantee that the decoded code is errorless, so the best and more ethical way, again, is to contact the library developer as mentioned in the answer above.